# What level of magic prowess did Harry Potter have?

Tags: harry-potter

I have a question in reading Harry Potter yet again.  How strong, vs. Voldemort aside, is Harry?  We see all these comparisons, like Snape and his potions book, Tom and his accomplishments, the twins and their abilities, and Dummbldor.  So, is there anything that we might base his magic level on?  I mean, it seems that he lacks a strong magic knowledge.  He mentions at the end of Goblet of knowing a boatload of hexes when giving the gold to the twins.  I reference Robert Jordan and his epic Wheel of Time where each user of the Power could sense strength, how do we know relative strengths with magic, and where would Harry stand?

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive canon answer to this question. To me it's way subjective.

Comment: His power is to entice the red haired girl to keep saving his bacon.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few instances where Harry shows he's quite adept at magic...

One such example is the Patronus Charm, in the Harry Potter Universe he was one of the youngest wizards able to cast Patronus.  He was even able to give it a corporeal form as a stag.

[image: Harry Potter Patronus Stag]